# C# Azure Function compare changes between two Blobs

Tags: c#, azure-functions, azure-blob-storage

I am working on an Azure Function that should read two .csv files stored as Blobs in Azure Blob Storage and return a third, new, blob with lines that are different between both input blobs.

For example:

```
csv1:
12,aaa,bbb,ccc,ddd,eee,fff
13,aaa,bbb,ccc,ddd,eee,fff

csv2:
12,bbb,aaa,ccc,ddd,eee,fff
13,aaa,bbb,ccc,ddd,eee,fff
14,aaa,bbb,ccc,ddd,eee,fff

Output csv:
12,bbb,aaa,ccc,ddd,eee,fff
14,aaa,bbb,ccc,ddd,eee,fff
```

So far I have been able to read the Blob files but I have been unsuccessful in comparing them directly. I did manage to get it to work by reading in the Blobs and loading them into two different Datatables and perform the comparison between them. However, that method is far too slow and I am pretty sure there is a far more efficient way of handling it.

(Being more at home with Powershell, the Compare-Object function is kinda the exact thing I would love to create).

I can load in the Blobs using either the .DownloadText() or the .DownloadToStream() methods so getting the Blob contents is no problem.

```
blobA = container.GetBlockBlobReference("FileA");
blobB = container.GetBlockBlobReference("FileB");

string blobContentsA = blobA.DownloadText();
string blobContentsB = blobB.DownloadText();
```

or

```
string textA;
using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
  {
  blobA.DownloadToStream(memoryStream);
  textA = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(memoryStream.ToArray());
  }

string textB;
using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
  {
  blobA.DownloadToStream(memoryStream);
  textB = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(memoryStream.ToArray());
  }
```

I tried the code below but then I get a "cannot convert from 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable' to 'string'" message so I guess I have to do something there, but what I have no clue to be honest.

Comment: If you want that cmdlet in C#, why not use the source? : https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/blob/master/src/Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.Utility/commands/utility/compare-object.cs

Comment: You can use a tool like that: https://github.com/mmanela/diffplex. I used it in the past and worked great :-)